# Django Test server occasional -"Refused to connect error message"

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I am hosting my Django Test server on Digital Ocean .

I have virtualenv under which  when tester requires they just run the python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

However occasionally tester gets "Refused to connect error message"
But I do not see any error message on the server side 
[image]

[image]
What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you using nginx as a proxy (per the DO guides to setting up django/one-click installs) or just bare runserver?

Comment: I use bare runserver.

Comment: Ok, if you're going to xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000 on your DO droplet, and getting 'cannot connect', then it's likely that nginx is in fact running in front of your test server.  Try checking the DO guidance on it, as I suspect that's the most likely culprit.  If you're using a domain name on your droplet, then it likely needs set up in the networking tab on DO.

Comment: Thanks . possible, I am illiterate in this domain. Was following some tutorial and when things didn't work for me in the middle just started to run test server as a workaround.